# OSX script editor with AppleScript

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

My wish is to create a snippet which launch some bash command when I double-click. I was hoping find one solution with Automator. But I do not understand how it works.

So I tried AppleScript with the script editor, but I got some issues.

Here I have this code:

```
on run
    activate
    do shell script "/opt/homebrew/bin/npx igir report --dat DAT --input ROM > report.txt && find . -name .* -exec rm {} \\;"
end run
```

I have this message: sh: report.txt: Read-only file system

Then, I tried this code:

```
on run
    activate
    do shell script "/opt/homebrew/bin/npx igir report --dat DAT --input ROM > /Users/me/Downloads/ROM/report.txt && find . -name .* -exec rm {} \\;"
end run
```

Now, I got this error: env: node: No such file or directory

NOTE: I would like change "me" on last code by some variable (like: {user}).

Please do you have some ideas? Thanks.

Call a bash script in a Ap snippet.

Comment: If you just run the `npx` part of your shell command, without the `find` part, does it work? As to the `find` command, what files are you attempting to delete?

Comment: That `find` command probably didn't execute in the directory you think it did, and it's probably deleted some things that shouldn't have been deleted. Do you have a backup of your home directory?

Comment: @GordonDavisson - well put

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments.
@Mockman: if I delete the find part, I got this error: sh: report.txt: Read-only file system

Comment: @GordonDavisson: before I start the script, I create an App 'module' and click on the icon right on a folder I want and nothing was deleted, I checked.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "...and click on the icon right on a folder I want...", but I don't think that it's going to have any effect on where the `find` command runs.

Comment: When I save the script, I select App. Then I double click on the icon and yeah you right, find have absolutely no effect.

Comment: @OVER-C `find` didn't have the effect you expected, but it did have some effects you didn't expect. AppleScript apps seem to run with a working directory of / (i.e. the root of the filesystem), so that `find` command is going to search the entire filesystem (subject to various permissions, privacy, etc restrictions), and try to delete every file and directory that starts with "." *in the entire filesystem*. It will have failed in a lot of cases, but where it succeeded... random things may be broken throughout your system.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: OK Gordon I understand, do you know how I can make it work with the nix command? I will see find later. My main concern it's the npc igir. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with nix, but I'd guess the problem with that is either something like a wrong default directory (similar to the find problem) or missing environment setup (`do shell script` will not generally run commands with the same environment as an interactive shell).

Answer (score 1):

By trying to redirect the output of `npx` to "report.txt" — a relative path — you are relying on the working directory of the application, which is generally `/`.  Since that is on the read-only system volume, you get a "Read-only file system error."

Your second attempt, directing the output to an absolute path in your home directory, is better, but assumes that there is a folder "ROM" in the Downloads folder, so you might have to make it first using `mkdir`.

If that folder already exists, then I am not sure what the issue is, but it is worth mentioning that "do shell script" does *not* read your usual shell startup files and therefore does not have any `PATH` customizations you may have made there — `npx` may be relying on that.

You also asked about substituting `/Users/me`: you can use the variable `${HOME}`, or since this is a shell, just `~`; for example `~/Downloads`.

These and other questions are addressed in [TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).